# File runs from python.exe

Tags: python

I just switch laptops and everything seems to be normal except this. When I open CMD and try to run a file like `py filename.py`

it comes up with an error

`C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: can't open file 'filename.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

It defaults to the python.exe file. It does it for every file that I try to run as well. I am in the correct directory (the directory where the actual file is in) but it keeps defaulting to that error. I am running windows 10 with python 3.7.3.

Comment: What does the `dir` command show in the directory where your `filename.py` file lives?  If you created that file by using an editor like Notepad then it's possible that the file is really named `filename.py.txt`, but you won't notice it in File Explorer if the view options are set to "hide well-known file extensions" because that will hide the `.txt` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change the default directory where your terminal looks for the python.exe file and its packages. You must change both. One variable points to the python[version] folder and the other points to the python[version]\scripts folder.

This page shows you how to redirect your terminal in windows:

https://superuser.com/questions/1399544/how-to-change-default-python-executable-on-windows-10/1399546

Another tip is that you must change these two identical directories for both the "user variables" and the "system variables" listed in the section below it. I believe the Python installation has probs with this, especially if it's a reinstall or a failed update. And on Windows in general.

Best,